# Pen color change within a loop in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am migrating some Windows programs to Web technologies. Basically use System.Drawing, so I'm using JavaScript, and of course Canvas. As a conceptual practice, I try to draw a mesh on Canvas (see image), Cool, I am very close, but I can't get the color of the dark lines alternates. What should I do?

[image: Sample]

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5) // waiting a line of one pixel

let shift = 0;
let w = canvas.clientWidth;

while (shift <= w) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = shift % 40 == 0 ? 'gray' : 'silver';
  ctx.moveTo(shift, w)
  ctx.lineTo(w, w - shift);
  shift += 10;
}
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" class="plot" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: shift % 10 == 0 for array [0, 10, 20, 30, ... ] gives always the same value

Comment: DraganS is right. But it is not the only reason. Even if we tried to change the increment value of shift so that the test did not always have the same value, we would have the same result. This is because you only call the stroke method once and since it is the stroke method that draws on the screen, it will only draw with the last color assigned to strokeStyle.

Answer (score 5):

This might be fine

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5) // waiting a line of one pixel

let shift = 0;
let w = canvas.clientWidth;

while (shift <= w) {
  ctx.strokeStyle = shift % 100 == 0 ? 'gray' : 'silver';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(shift, w)
  ctx.lineTo(w, w - shift);
  shift += 10;
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```